# transition toggle between divs in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to apply toggle between divs. But I couldn't make it happen. I know I can't put two elements inside the transition. I need to a `transition-group` for that. But when I use group, then it says `bind` the elements inside group. But I am not looping the elements... So I am a bit stuck about solving this...

**template**

```
<div>
    <transition name="view">
        <map-view 
            v-show="this.screenView == 'map'" 
            :changeView="changeView" />    
        <list-view 
            v-show="this.screenView === 'list'"
            :changeView="changeView" />               
    </transition>            
</div>
```

**script**

```
methods: {
    changeView(screen){
        this.screenView = screen;
    }
}
```

**styles**

```
.view-enter-active, .view-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.view-enter, .view-leave-to {
  opacity: 0
}
```

By the way `changeView()` is working. No problem about that part. Just trying to toggle between divs.

Comment: The key can be any static value.  `key="map"`, `key="list"`.  It doesn't matter.  Or you can use `transition` and `v-if`.

Comment: If I give different keys to elements then second elements doesn't take any effect from transition... the first element(map) is fine though... something is off... @StevenB.

Comment: You're using `transition-group` right?

Comment: A working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x62jqar7/).

Comment: Thank you for the advice and also fiddle. I just did the same thing and it's working now. @StevenB.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to advice in the comments.

I tried to give different keys to elements.

```
    <transition-group name="view">
        <map-view 
            key="maps"
            v-show="this.screenView == 'map'" 
            :changeView="changeView" />    
        <list-view 
            key="list"
            v-show="this.screenView === 'list'"
            :changeView="changeView" />               
    </transition-group>
```

and changed the styles like below.

```
.view-enter-active, .view-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, transform 0.5s ease;
}
.view-enter-active {
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.view-enter, .view-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.view-enter-to, .view-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

It's working now.